# Redirect subdomain to new domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I am trying to redirect pages like:

```
c.domain1.se/folder1/main.html
```

to

```
www.domain2.se/folder1/main.html
```

My htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} c\.domain1\.se$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ domain2.se%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L,NE]
```

I get the following message:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /set on this server.
```

Webhost claims there are no other htaccess files interfering with the one on c.domain1.se.

**Any ideas on what could be the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the scheme in the rule's target and add boundary to the condition match (via `^`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^c\.domain1\.se$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.se%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^c\.domain1\.se$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.se%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```